# Closing MemoryStream in async task

Tags: c#, task, async-await

I am writing code that loads multiple instances of the same task at once and waits for them all to finish. Each task reads from a file and uploads a byte array of a portion of that file.

```
var requests = new Task[parts.Count];
foreach (var part in parts)
{
    var partNumber = part.Item1;
    var partSize = part.Item2;
    var ms = new MemoryStream(partSize);
    var bw = new BinaryWriter(ms);

    var offset = (partNumber - 1) * partMaxSize;
    var count = partSize;
    bw.Write(assetContentBytes, offset, count);

    ms.Position = 0;
    Console.WriteLine("beginning upload of part " + partNumber);
    requests[partNumber - 1] = uploadClient.UploadPart(uploadResult.AssetId, partNumber, ms);
}

await Task.WhenAll(requests);
```

I would like to close these MemoryStreams after the related task is complete, but if I write stream.Close() into the loop, the streams close before the task is complete. Is it possible to close each stream after the task is complete? Thanks.

Comment: Seems like `UploadPart` is Synchronous call. Close ms after it

Comment: What is `uploadClient` here?

Comment: @L.B Well that method returns a `Task`.  What makes you think it's synchronous?

Comment: @Servy, by convention, async methods should have a name ending with Async. But in this case, it's obvious from the usage that it returns a task...

Comment: @Servy I missed that part. Thanks for your politeness...

Comment: Thank you, everyone. I will add Async to my method for clarity.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just extract the part that uses the stream to another async method:

```
    var requests = new Task[parts.Count];
    foreach (var part in parts)
    {
        var partNumber = part.Item1;
        var partSize = part.Item2;
        requests[partNumber - 1] = UploadPartAsync(partNumber, partSize);
    }

    await Task.WhenAll(requests);

...

async Task UploadPartAsync(int partNumber, int partSize)
{
    using (var ms = new MemoryStream(partSize))
    using (var bw = new BinaryWriter(ms))
    {
        var offset = (partNumber - 1) * partMaxSize;
        var count = partSize;
        bw.Write(assetContentBytes, offset, count);

        ms.Position = 0;
        Console.WriteLine("beginning upload of part " + partNumber);
        await uploadClient.UploadPart(uploadResult.AssetId, partNumber, ms);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this is straightforward.